# JS, "objects", this and that. Coming from python THIS really confuses me. (pun intended)

Tags: javascript, python, html, oop

Heres a bit of cleaned up code from a picture gallery im writing to learn js.
I create the gallery as an object but at some point i lose track of what "this" points to.
It doesnt make sense to me what happens at the bottom (look at the comments).
Can someone please explain?

```
function Gallery(parentID)
{
        // ...
    this.showDiv = document.createElement("div");
        // ...
    this.show = function ()
        {
        document.body.appendChild(this.showDiv); //will be given css absolute position to "pop up"
        this.showDiv.innerHTML = '<img class="displayImage" src="' + this.picList[this.showIndex] + '">'; //fill with image
        this.showDiv.focus();
        this.showDiv.onclick = this.hide;
        }   

    this.hide = function ()
        {
        alert(this.innerHTML); // <= WHY DOES THIS SHOW THE INNERHTML CONTENTS OF this.showDiv??????
            //alert(this.showDiv.innerHTML); // <= shouldnt this be correct?
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this); //doesnt work
        }
}
```

Let me know if i cleaned up some code that might have affected the results and ill fill it in.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd do much better doing it the JavaScript way; `this.show` should instead be defined, after `Gallery`, as `Gallery.prototype.show`. Ditto for `hide`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    this.showDiv.onclick = this.hide;
```

This line is the problem. It doesn’t work like in Python; `this.hide` is not a bound method. It’s just the `hide` function, not bound to any particular `this`.

One way to fix it is:

```
    this.showDiv.onclick = this.hide.bind(this);
```

But the `.bind()` method of functions is a rather new standard; it isn’t in all old browsers. So you might want to roll your own instead:

```
function bindMethod(object, func) {
    return function () { return func.apply(object, arguments); };
}

this.showDiv.onclick = bindMethod(this, this.hide);
```

(Generally `this` is kind of strangely behaved in JavaScript; the main thing to remember is that `this` always refers to the innermost function’s `this`, which could be whatever the caller wants it to be. Sometimes you see JS code do things like `var self = this;` to give a particular function’s `this` a name that can be used in nested functions; in Python, of course, that is just sort of the way things work automatically.)

Comment: +1 for `var self = this;`. If you're finding it hard to predict the scope of `this`, it always helps to define your own.

Comment: The significant thing is that when an event is called, `this` refers to the DOM element for which the event was triggered.

Comment: amagad `var self = this;` is brilliant! is this common practice or a hack?

Comment: Well, it’s sort of both :) but definitely a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the object that called the function. So when you say `this.showDiv.onclick`, showDiv is what is calling the function. Therefore `this.innerHTML` actually means `this.showDiv.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a constructor function, rather than a factory, then keep `this` in mind --

If you have a method (or any function you call as a method, and not as a constructor), and that method references `this`, that `this` statement gets resolved at the instant the function is ***called*** rather than when it is defined.

```
function sayName () { console.log(this.name); }

var bob = { name : "Bob" },
      doug = { name : "Doug" };

bob.greet = sayName;
doug.greet = sayName;
```

In a strict class-based language, there'd be all kinds of errors, here.

But through the magic of late-binding (deciding what `this` means at the last possible second, during execution), it goes off without a hitch.

There is one hitch, however:
Functions inside of functions.
You want `this` to point to the `this` of the outer method.
It doesn't.
In old (current) JS, it points at `window`.
In future JS, it points at nothing.

```
function sayNameAndAge () {
   var outerThis = this,
         name = this.name;

   function sayAge () { console.log(outerThis.age); }

     console.log(name);
     sayAge();
 }
```

Assuming Bob has both a name and an age, now, you can assign the function like last time, and it will work.
The function will see that `bob` was in front of the dot, and thus the subject of `this` (note: not really how it works, but how it appears to work, one function deep).  `outerThis` will save the reference for the inner function to use.

Another option is:

```
sayNameAndAge.call(bob);
```

`call` is a method that functions have (did I mention that functions are objects), which lets you specify `this` for that particular execution, rather than giving another object a method (a reference, really).

`bind` works just like `call`, except it returns a function where the `this` is permanently set to value you passed in.  And `bind` isn't in OldIE.

One other major point of reference:
When you use event-listeners, `this` points to the element you put the listener on.

You can delegate listeners (attaching one listener to a `<ul>`, that listens for any click on any of its `<li>`, for example.
In that instance, `this` would be the `<ul>`, because it would be the object which the listener was attached to, when it was triggered.

Hope that makes things a little clearer.